# creating query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the best way to create a query by one select command to find exact results for below keywords:

```
‘‘Question About Programming’’ 
‘‘Question Programming About’’ 
‘‘Programming About Question’’ 
‘‘Programming Question About’’ 
‘‘About Programming Question’’ 
‘‘About Question Programming’’
```

the above keywords are given by user so they can be used in the where condition in query.

Comment: Are you trying to get all rows that have a column exactly matching one of these strings?

Comment: research MySQL LIKE statement and the wildcard -%- sign, these will go a long way towards helping you

Comment: Look up Fulltext Search in MySQL

Comment: Absolutely second @juergen d's comment. Full-text searching is the best way to do this. You can read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @ryanyuyu : yes, I need all the rows which having one of the same sentences regardless if between they is any punctuation .   how if I use this?  
    Select * from table where name like '%question%' or '%about%' or '%programming%' or like  '%question%' or '%programming%' or '%about%' ....

Answer (score 0):

Use `Like` operator

```
select * from 
yourtable
where col like '%about%'
and col like '%programming%'
and col like '%question%'
```

Comment: Downvoter can you please comment so that i can improve my answer

Comment: Chances are they've already left. Not to mention your question could come back results he's not interested in. What if there's a value for "Question about programming a batsignal." Maybe he's not interested in that.

Comment: Or there's the fact that using a double Wildcard makes your query non sargable.

Comment: @Zane - yeah i know but the sample data doesn't have your what if anaylsis part(`a batsignal`)

Comment: Obviously however chances are sample data isn't all he has and in the real world your answer could come back with unwanted results.

Comment: Like `Programming questionable roundabouts`, for instance.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name in ('Question About Programming', 
                      'Question Programming About', 
                      'Programming About Question', 
                      'Programming Question About', 
                      'About Programming Question', 
                      'About Question Programming')
```

Comment: I guess it must be good, but how about when we have punctuation?